# How to query to Session Id to call the REST API in salesforce from third party applications

Tags: api

I built a REST API in salesforce which allows a third application to make a call to salesforce through POST method and I return the JSON response back based on the Account Name posted. I'm not able to get the session Id which I need for authentication. I'm just looking for a basic authentication. How to query the session id  and allow the third part applications to call the apex api.

```
 @RestResource(urlMapping='/test/test_rest_api/*')
    global class RestTestController {
    @HttpPost
    global static void getTestAccount() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    String jsonResponse = '';
    String accountName = req.params.get('account_name');
   // No account_name parameter was found; return status 400
    if(accountName == null) {
        res.statusCode = 400;
        jsonResponse = '{"response": {"status": "Failure", "message": "MissingRequiredQueryParameter account_name"}}';
        res.responseBody = blob.valueOf(jsonResponse);
        return;
    }

// Get the list of accounts that match the account_name sent in the request.
    List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Fax, Website
                              FROM Account
                              WHERE Name =: accountName];

// No accounts with matching account_name
    if( accounts.isEmpty()) {
        res.statusCode = 400;
        jsonResponse = '{"response": {"status": "Failure", "message": "No account matching account_name was found"}}';
        res.responseBody = blob.valueOf(jsonResponse);
        return;
    }

// At least 1 account was found, JSON serialize it and send it back.
    try {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        jsonResponse = Json.serialize(accounts[0]);
        res.responseBody = blob.valueOf(jsonResponse);
        return;
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        res.statusCode = 500;
        jsonResponse = '{"response": {"status": "Failure", "message": "' + ex + '"}}';
        res.responseBody = blob.valueOf(jsonResponse);
        return;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your (presumably external to Salesforce) application will need to obtain the session ID by first authenticating with Salesforce. Once the authentication is complete you will be returned a session ID (AKA an access token) that can then be included in the request to your REST API. See e.g. [Understanding Authentication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm).

Getting the authentication logic right is typically trickier than implementing the REST API. Plan for this to take several hours of research followed by probably rather more hours of configuration/coding/testing.